# Conditional to add_host module

Tags: ansible

I have an inventory that i need to add a conditional to.

My code:

```
    - name: Create memory inventory
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.0.key }}"
        group: target_hosts
      with_nested:
        - "{{ lookup ('dict', hosts, wantlist=True) }}"
```

But I want something like:

```
    - name: Create memory inventory
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.0.key }}"
{% if item.0.value.OS_Choice[:3] == 'win' %}
        group: 
          - target_hosts
          - win
{% else %}
        group: 
          - target_hosts
          - linux
{% endif %}
      with_nested:
        - "{{ lookup ('dict', hosts, wantlist=True) }}"
```

With this configuration, Ansible errors:

```
The offending line appears to be:
        {% if item.0.value.OS_Choice[:3] == 'win' %}
         ^ here
```

Any ideas on how I can implement this conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up Jinja2 with YAML. Here you go:

```yaml
    - name: Create memory inventory when win
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.0.key }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ lookup ('dict', hosts, wantlist=True) }}"
      when: item.0.value.OS_Choice[:3] == 'win'
      vars:
        group: 
          - target_hosts
          - win

    - name: Create memory inventory when not win
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item.0.key }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ lookup ('dict', hosts, wantlist=True) }}"
      when: item.0.value.OS_Choice[:3] != 'win'
      vars:
        group: 
          - target_hosts
          - linux
```

However, Ansible [gather facts about the OS already](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement). Perhaps you want to use those, instead of configuring something like this yourself.

Comment: Shouldn't `group` be `groups` and present as a module parameter instead of `vars`?

Comment: Many thanks, I should have thought of that.  I can't use Ansible facts at this point because the hosts haven't yet been provisioned.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on Kevin's answer (and fixing some wrongly placed parameters)

You should definitely do this differently, like creating dynamic groups based on detected OS in facts. See:

- the [`group_by` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_by_module.html#group-by-module)
- the `ansible_distribution*` facts that you can explore as an example with

  ```sh
  ansible localhost -m setup -a filter="ansible_distribution*"
  ```

Meanwhile, with your current logic, you can still do this in a single task:

```yaml
- name: Create memory inventory
  vars:
    additional_group: >-
      {{ (item.0.value.OS_Choice[:3] == 'win') | ternary('win', 'linux') }}
  add_host:
    name: "{{ item.0.key }}"
    groups:
      - target_hosts
      - "{{ additional_group }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ lookup ('dict', hosts, wantlist=True) }}"
```

Comment: I can't use detected facts as, at this point, the hosts don't exist outside of a data dictionary.  This is one playbook in a series in AWX that takes a dictionary of hosts and properties and builds those hosts in oVirt and Foreman